# Не выводится значение переменной $_SESSION в другом файле

Tags: php

Сделал простую форму регистрации и авторизации. Хочу в шапке сайта сделать личный кабинет. Для этого нужно вывести имя пользователя. Но выводится это имя только в момент авторизации. Когда я перехожу на другие страницы это имя пропадает.

**login.php**

```
$user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
if( $user )
{
    if ( hash_equals($user->password, md5($data['password'])) ) {
        $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
}
```

**header.php**

```
  <?php
 if( !isset($_SESSION['logged_user']) ) : ?>
   <div class="login">
        <a href="../pages/login.php">Войти</a>
        <a href="../pages/signup.php">Регистрация</a>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php 
    echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login; ?> <!--Вот это имя не выводится-->
Авторизован!
<div class="login">
 <a href="../pages/logout.php">Выйти</a>
   </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Еще интересно, что он не выводит данные именно из бд. Пробовал также выводить из массива $_SESSION простую строку, все работает нормально.

session_start() есть в каждом файле.

А вот, что показывает var_damp($_SESSION['logged_user']))

```
 object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (11) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(19) "RedBeanPHP\OODBBean" ["properties":protected]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["login"]=> string(5) "ivan " ["email"]=> string(10) "fwefw@fdsf" ["password"]=> string(32) "698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668" } ["__info":protected]=> array(7) { ["type"]=> string(5) "users" ["sys.id"]=> string(2) "id" ["sys.orig"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["login"]=> string(5) "ivan " ["email"]=> string(10) "fwefw@fdsf" ["password"]=> string(32) "698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668" } ["tainted"]=> bool(false) ["changed"]=> bool(false) ["changelist"]=> array(0) { } ["model"]=> NULL } ["beanHelper":protected]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#2 (1) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(44) "RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper" } ["fetchType":protected]=> NULL ["withSql":protected]=> string(0) "" ["withParams":protected]=> array(0) { } ["aliasName":protected]=> NULL ["via":protected]=> NULL ["noLoad":protected]=> bool(false) ["all":protected]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: используйте функцию var_dump() и посмотрите, что в сессиях хранится

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['logged_user']->login) возвращает NULL. Хотя var_dump($_SESSION['logged_user']) показывает, что там хранится значение.

Comment: $user я так понимаю это activeRecord?

Comment: https://www.cryptologie.net/article/268/how-to-compare-password-hashes-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо начинать сессию *после* инициализации автозагрузчика классов. Например, так:

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
```

Либо можно вручную загружать классы, которые могут быть сохранены в сессии, до начала сессии.

Если PHP настроен на автоматический запуск сессии, то [такое поведение нужно отключить](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start).

Comment: В сессии класс хранится в сериализованном виде, например, в файлах или базе. Когда вы переходите на другую страницу, то php пытается восстановить класс User, но не находит его и выдает __PHP_Incomplete_Class. Как советует @sanmai подключайте скрипты до инициализации сессии.

Answer (score 0):

По видимому, сессия не может найти класс $user, отсюда получается вот это object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class).

Попробуйте добавлять в сессию не $user, а новый класс. Или создать класс User, который заполните необходимой информацией и уже его присвоить к сессии.

```
var $_user = new StdClass();
$_user->login = $user->login;
...
```

Возможно добавлять не класс, а просто хранить поля

```
$_SESSION['logged_user']['login'] = $user->login;
...
```